# Calling on a constructor within a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I am working on an assignment with the following instructions(not entirely, just the portion I'm struggling to understand):

Include two constructors.  The first takes no arguments and sets the savingsBalance variables to zero and sets the savingsAccountName to an empty string by calling the second (i.e. two argument) constructor with 0 and an empty string.  The second constructor takes one double argument (the savingsBalance) and one string argument (the savingsAccountName), and sets the savingsBalance by calling the setSavingsBalance method and setsavingsAccountName method, respectively.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working properly so I'm sure I'm missing it entirely.  Could anyone offer any assistance and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
public SavingsAccount()
    {
        savingsBalance = 0;
        SavingsAccount baseAccount = new SavingsAccount(0, "");
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance, string name)
    {
        balance = getSavingsBalance();
        name = getSavingsAccountName();
    }
```

Comment: Passing a double by value and overwriting it in the constructor does not make any sense at all

Comment: Hmm. I think you should suggest to your instructor that using single/double precision floating point data types for financial calculations is just plain wrong. Decimal is the right choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `this` keyword.

```
    public SavingsAccount():this(0,"")
    {

    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance, string name)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Comment: This was it exactly, thank you very much!  I need to research the "this" function a bit more to understand it fully, but I can see now how my previous code was ignoring the parameters and setting its own.  Anyways, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the fields or properties of your class.You are just changing the value of arguments passed to the constructor.

```
public SavingsAccount(double balance, string name)
{
    this.savingsBalance = balance;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Then you can call it from the parameterless constructor

```
public SavingsAccount(): this(0 , "")
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to **`cascade constructors`** to call one constructor from other.

```
public SavingsAccount() : this(0 , "")
{
}
```

And of course you need to set the class level fields from other constructor:

```
public SavingsAccount(double balance, string name)
{
    this.balance = balance;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke one constructor from another only if it is the first operation in the constructor. This is enforced by making call in the method signature.

```
public SomeConstructor():this("foo"){
}
public SomeConstructor(string someParam){
}
```